# How to detect the end of Promise.all

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to get a response when all the promises are complete, every promise is a diferent process of web scraping. This is the output that I get for the following code as you can see all finished is the first output how to get in the end?

```
all finished
partial end
partial end
partial end
```

Code in NodeJs using puppeteer

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const URLs = [
    'https://www.google.es/search?q=dog&sxsrf=ALiCzsaZ5RIpFrQHMAxy9uZ9vbCu2wDAlw:1662240805949&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjp7ZPGyfn5AhVEgv0HHSbDC1oQ_AUoAXoECAIQAw&biw=1280&bih=576&dpr=2',
    'https://www.google.es/search?q=dog&sxsrf=ALiCzsaZ5RIpFrQHMAxy9uZ9vbCu2wDAlw:1662240805949&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjp7ZPGyfn5AhVEgv0HHSbDC1oQ_AUoAXoECAIQAw&biw=1280&bih=576&dpr=2',
    'https://www.google.es/search?q=dog&sxsrf=ALiCzsaZ5RIpFrQHMAxy9uZ9vbCu2wDAlw:1662240805949&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjp7ZPGyfn5AhVEgv0HHSbDC1oQ_AUoAXoECAIQAw&biw=1280&bih=576&dpr=2'
];

main();

async function main() {
    await scrapingUrls().then(console.log("all finished"));
}

async function scrapingUrls() {
    const prom = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < URLs.length; i++) {
      prom.push(scrapInformation(URLs[i]));
    }
    return await Promise.all([prom]);
}

function scrapInformation(url) {
    return new Promise(async function(resolve, reject) {
      const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
      const page = await browser.newPage()
  
      await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
      
      await browser.close().then(function () {
        console.log('partial end');
        resolve();
      })
    });
  }
```

Comment: [Never pass an `async function` as the executor to `new Promise`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43036229/1048572)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

> ```
> await scrapingUrls().then(console.log("all finished"));
> ```

is wrong. You should give a function to .then():

```
await scrapingUrls().then(() => console.log("all finished"));
```

Here the `console.log("all finished")` is executed right away.

Also:

> ```
> return await Promise.all([prom]);
> ```

just `prom` without the brackets.